# Finding elements by style using pandas

Tags: html, pandas, parsing, tags

In the parser I am currently working on I am able to find and print elements I search for within  tags correctly by filtering by style. However, when I try to extract from within the  tags bs4 does not find my result when i filter by the style. 
This is what I have for the  tags that works:

```
eventData = soup.find_all("div", style = "margin-right: 8px; padding: 8px 0px 16px 16px; overflow: hidden; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); font-size: 15px;")
# append each event as a list within datalist
for i in range(0, len(eventData)):
    eventElement = html_text.extract_text(str(eventData[i]))
    numEvents.append(eventElement)
print("Events Date, Time & Location: ", eventElement)
print("# of Events:", len(numEvents))
```

correct result:

Events Date, Time & Location:  Friday, January 24 at 5:00PM EST
 of Events: 1

and this is what does not work:

```
datalist = []  # empty list to hold html text
# search for the required text for events
EventName = soup.find_all("h3", style = "font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600; overflow: hidden; margin: 2px 0px 5px; line-height: 20px; display: -webkit-box; max-width: 400px; -webkit-line-clamp: 2; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; text-overflow: ellipsis;")

for i in range(0, len(EventName)):
    eventName = html_text.extract_text(str(EventName[i]))
    datalist.append(eventName)
print("\n")
print("Event Name: ", str(EventName))
print("# of Items: ", len(EventName))
```

The print("# of items: ") says there are 0 items, but when I remove the style filter:

EventName = soup.find_all("h3")

The result says there are two items(the search bar also has the h3 tag), and gives me a result of the html of the page instead of the string as it is supposed to. How can I fix this to get my result to print a string as it does with the 3 other div tags throughout my parser?
I am aware bs4 has some issues finding things like this, so if I should use another library please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue: 
i needed to change

```
print("Event Name: ", str(EventName))
```

to:

```
print("Event Name: ", str(eventName))
```

which then gave me the correct result of the event name. 
The simplest of mistakes.